# How to get latest record based on date and time in Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get latest record based on date and  time , but column contains time is in 12 Hours AM/PM format.

Suppose my records in

2015-09-07 12:50:37.1983315 PM - Coming this record

2015-09-07  03:12:15.1983315 PM - Actually I need to get this record.

The above result came by below query..

```
 SELECT top 10 * FROM SHAdminMessageIndex where Appid='62001308607984608300' and 
 PolicyNumber='0081317' order by BeginTime desc
```

So how to get the result by using 12 hours format with AM and PM. Thanks in Advance

Comment: what is the datatype on column BeginTime?

Comment: You want the first record of each day? Which sql-server version are you using?

Comment: So you store date and time in a string? Not a datetime? Why? Change your table so as to work with datetime instead and there will be no problem querying the data.

Comment: You should definitely [use the correct data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) and your problems will ease, but your title conflicts with your sample data, the title suggests you want the *"latest"* record, but in your example the date you have indicated you want is the *earliest* of the two?

Comment: @Sanjay If it is possible, fix this column's data type NOW. Having to wrap that column in a convert/cast and have it as part of your where or order by will result in the entire table being scanned (consistently poor performance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 SELECT top 10 * FROM SHAdminMessageIndex 
    where Appid='62001308607984608300' and  PolicyNumber='0081317' 
    order by 
    cast(BeginTime as datetime2)  desc
```

OR

```
SELECT top 10 * FROM SHAdminMessageIndex 
where Appid='62001308607984608300' and  PolicyNumber='0081317' 
order by 
cast(left(BeginTime,charindex('.',BeginTime)-1)+right(BeginTime,2) as datetime)  desc
```

Comment: Sorry for not mentioned. Datatype is nvarchar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT top 10 * FROM SHAdminMessageIndex where Appid='62001308607984608300'   
and  PolicyNumber='0081317' order by  stuff(convert(varchar(19), BeginTime,  
126),11,1,' ') desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the first record of each day? You can group by date and take the first of each group. Therefore use a ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER` and a `CTE`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT t.*, 
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(BeginTime AS Date) ORDER BY BeginTime )
    FROM SHAdminMessageIndex t
    WHERE Appid='62001308607984608300' 
    AND   PolicyNumber='0081317'
)
SELECT TOP 10 CTE.* 
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY BeginTime DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This is why we should always use proper datatype to store the data. Try Casting the `BeginTime` to `DATETIME2`

```
SELECT top 10 * 
FROM SHAdminMessageIndex 
where Appid='62001308607984608300' 
and PolicyNumber='0081317' 
order by Cast(BeginTime  AS DATETIME2) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PARSE to convert your string to DATETIME2.

```
select top 10 * 
from SHAdminMessageIndex 
where Appid='62001308607984608300' and PolicyNumber='0081317'
order by parse(BeginTime as datetime2 using 'en-US') desc;
```

Make sure to specify the language such as not to be dependent from session settings - your datetime string may not be a valid datetime in another language (in many languages PM and AM are not valid).

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7d/366.